# Comma separated string into two column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a solution from a comma separated string. I have a function which returns a list of rows of one column

```
declare @datap varchar(200)
set @datap = 'KIA,A,TEST1,I,KIA2,A,KIA2,A,KIA3,I'
select * from dbo.fs_1_fn_split(@datap, ',')
```

it gives in this form or also in one column named value as showing in column 2

```
id  value
1   KOA
2   A
3   TEST1
4   I
5   KIA2
6   A
7   KIA2
8   A
9   KIA3
10  I
```

well I need to convert this in two columns as

```
KOA    A
TEST1  I
KIA2   A
.....
```

Comment: Please post the source code for dbo.fs_1_fn_split

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by aggregating the results after you split out the values.  Here is one approach:

```
select max(case when id % 2 = 1 then value end) as value1,
       max(case when id % 2 = 0 then value end) as value2       
from (select id, value, (id-1)/2 as grp
      from dbo.fs_1_fn_split(@datap, ',') 
     ) t
group by grp
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have a similar task in which I need to use 3 column from another comma separated string in SQL, do I have to use id % 3 = 1 and 0 and inside sql (id-1)/3 as grp?

Comment: @qazifarhan . . . Yes.  Use the modulus operator to choose which of the three.  Use `/ 3` to put the records into groups of three.